# How can I identify GIF files that were written by FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, gif

I have lot of gif files, several thousand.

Some of them was created by me, and I nearly always used ffmpeg when encoding the gif.

Now I would like to select those animations from the large collection, which was created by me.

Maybe I could narrow the number of gif files which need an examination by viewing, if I would be able to select those somehow, which were created by ffmpeg.

Answer (score 4):

The GIF format does not have any metadata fields that could help you identify the writer. The binary format starts with a `GIF89a` header; the rest is image data.

So I'm afraid there's no way to automatically detect ffmpeg as a writer.

Comment: I agree. Meanwhile I tried to use the "strings" linux utility, to find some common strings in the GIFs, which are known was written by ffmpeg, but no success.

Comment: ffmpeg does not write any particular strings to GIF files. (Other formats like MP4 or MKV will have “writing application” tags like `Lavf58.29.100` which stands for libavformat, the FFmpeg library for writing containers.)